# Electron + NodeJs: fs.statSync() file size is always 0

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, fs

I'm developing a Electron app and i need to access a file's size. I'm using fs.statSync() to accomplish this.
My issue is that the fs.statSync() stats.size is always 0 (zero).

Here's how i'm getting the file size:

```
var stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
var fileSize = stats.size; //file size is always 0
console.log("fileSize: " + fileSize);
```

The Stats detailed object data:

```
Stats {dev: 1584160373, mode: 33206, nlink: 1, uid: 0, gid: 0…}
atime: Wed Oct 18 2017 23:39:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
birthtime: Wed Oct 18 2017 23:10:50 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
blksize: undefined
blocks: undefined
ctime: Thu Oct 19 2017 00:35:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
dev: 1584160373
gid: 0
ino: 8444249301430590
mode: 33206
mtime: Thu Oct 19 2017 00:35:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
nlink: 1
rdev: 0
size: 0
uid: 0
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Btw, i'm using Windows 10 x64.

**UPDATE: I solved my issue. The problem wasn't with fs.statSync(), but instead with the files (they were all 0 in size). Rookie mistake, my bad... ¯_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: I appear to be about 2.5 years behind you. I'm also creating files in electron that end up with size: 0. How did you create a file with the correct size?

Comment: I had to use `readFileSync` to the the file.

Comment: Hey @Birch the issue wasn't related to statSync() but with the fact that the files i was trying to read were empty :)
Check the question update: "I solved my issue. The problem wasn't with fs.statSync(), but instead with the files (they were all 0 in size). Rookie mistake, my bad... ¯_(ツ)_/¯"
Also, you can try fs.lstatSync().

Answer (score 0):

A folder has no size, the files in the folder do. You could walk recursive through all files and subfolders to collect each filesize. Or use a package like 'get-folder-size' for that.

If you are only running on windows or linux, you could try to get the folder size from a native program like `du -ksh path/to/folder` which will be faster to some degree.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the folder size, instead a file size. The "downloadFolder" variable has the path to the file. I've updated my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to determine if any other functions are taking up reading and writing of the file

Comment: Some asynchronous functions and so on

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31254101)